# Performance gap between training and validation/test data

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation, svm, unbalanced-classes

I have a heavily imbalanced binary classification task, where the prevalence of the negative event is around 3%. I shuffled then stratified split my data in train, test and validation, ensuring that I have the same percentage of samples from the negative class in each set. Since some negative samples are repeated (higher importance), I further ensured that the copies all lie either in training, or in validation or test (in order to avoid sample memorization). I resampled the training data using the SmoteENN technique, leaving validation and test unbalanced. For accuracy tracking, I use metrics which account for the prevalence of the negative event.

My problem is that I have perfect metric values for the training data, with a significant gap to the metric values on the validation and test data, which are very similar. The hyperparameter optimization tracks the model performance on the validation data.

First thought - **overfitting**. I tried using different resampling techniques on the training data, using cross validation and also using heavy regularization. The result is the same - even when the training metric values drop below perfection, I see the same performance drop in validation and test. The gap is however still present. I tried using different models, ranging from SVM to neural networks. The gap is present everywhere, but the more complex models still offer better metric values.

Second thought - **different train/test/validation distributions**. This should be covered by the initial shuffling of the data, before the stratified split. Since I however only have a limited amount of data (~500 of the negative events against thousands of positive events), can it be that this is really the explanation?

Are there any other explanations for the observed metrics? Is there anything I can do except gathering more data (not a possibility currently)?

Comment: Which algorithm you're using?

Comment: Different ones -  for example the SK Learn SVM with linear, rbf or poly kernel, MLP& CNN Neural Networks.

Comment: Do you observe the same issue without any SMOTE/over-/undersampling?

Comment: @MichaelM do you mean by using class weights instead (then yes) or simply by feeding the raw, unbalanced data to the algorithms?

Comment: I meant raw unbalanced data to see if there is also such gap.

Comment: yes, there is also a gap (at least when using the SVM with rbf kernel), with the addition that the performance values w.r.t. the metrics are worse than when using class weights or rebalancing

Comment: Can you train a model that outputs some score first (e.g. SVM with probability output) which then allows you to choose an appropriate working point/cutoff/threshold for your imbalanced problem?

Comment: yes of course. What is the idea - choose the threshold to reduce the gap? Do you propose to do this with the imbalanced or rebalanced data?

Comment: Imbalanced or rebalanced to the relative frequencies you'll have in your application. Then optimize threshold taking into account e.g. costs of false neg vs. false pos. (which tend not to be the same for many imbalanced applications - otherwise one typically wouldn't bother about setting up a classifier)

Comment: @cbeleites I just tried it out. Optimizing the threshold w.r.t. costs or Cohen Kappa value does not close the gap